# How do I root my Huawei S7-961wd aka PLDT Telpad QS?

Tags: rooting, root-access, huawei

I couldn't find any one-click (no PC needed) rooting solution for my PLDT Telpad QS.

Comment: Adding this to serve as one of the references found in the "How do I root my Android device?" wiki page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: @RossC NO! Please read the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). No rooting questions are closed as duplicate to that one since January 2012. One rooting question per device is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tick Unknown Sources
2. Download [Master Root](http://androidsenpai.blogspot.com/2013/12/root-master-apk.html?m=1) APK for Android 4.1.2 +
3. It's in Chinese, just follow through then click the RED button.
4. SuperSU will be installed automatically
5. Enjoy!

You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXDNWhzF2KA) for more information.